# What is passed into args []

Tags: java, command-line

What information is actually passed into the program if I pass a file using the command line?

Would this be the file name, or would it be the contents of the file?

Comment: Try it. Print the length of `args`, and then the contents of `args` in a loop.

Comment: You mean case of : java MyCode param1.txt ?? Then in that case its just a string value which you interpret to be a file name of param1.txt

Answer (score 0):

In Java, unlike in C/C++, the file name is not the first argument.

Only the arguments are in args[].